# Question about Sigma Algebra generated by a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given the following exercise:

[image]

I need to determine the sigma algebras generated by the random variables X and $S_1$ and show that they are independent under the first measure. $\sigma(S_1)$ should just consist of $\{\emptyset,\{H,T\} , H, T\}$, but I'm not sure about the elements of $\sigma(X)$. Do we have $$\sigma(X) = \{\emptyset, \Omega_2, HH, HT, TH, TT \}$$ or $$\sigma(X) = \{\emptyset, \Omega_2, \{HT, TH \}, \{HH, TT\}\}$$ I suppose it's the second case, because the first case doesn't yield independence under the first probability measure, but I'm not sure what the complement of e.g. $\{HH, TT \}$ is supposed to be and therefore whether this is actually a sigma-algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the sigma alebra generated by a random variable $Y$ on a finite universe $\Omega$ is
$$
\sigma(Y) = \{ Y^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal P(Y(\Omega)) \}
$$

so given the universe $\Omega = \{ HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ and the definition of $S_1$ and $S_2$ you clearly have

$$
\sigma(S_1) = \{\emptyset, \{ HH, HT\}, \{ TH, TT\}  ,\Omega\}
$$
$$
\sigma(X) = \{\emptyset,\{HT, TH \}, \{HH, TT \}, \Omega\}
$$

because

$X(\Omega) = \{0,1\}, \quad \mathcal P(X(\Omega)) = \{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\} \}$

$X^{-1}(\{ 1 \}) = \{HT, TH\},
\quad X^{-1}(\{ 0 \}) = \{HH, TT\}$

Comment: Why is $\{HH, TT \}^C = \{HT, TH \}$?

Comment: @eager2learn it's because $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$, and its compliment are a subset of those elements in $\Omega$ that are not in $A$, which are $\{HH, TT\}$